# get cummulative depreciation

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i have a table that shows list of items bought. from the table, the table shos depreciation rate per year to get the price calculation. from the calculation, i want to get how's the price change over year until the end date which is current date. the table looks like this

```
| item | bought_date | price  | depreciation_rate | end_date
| x    | 2018-01-12  | 5800   |  50               | 2020-01-17
| y    | 2015-06-01  | 9200   |  20               | 2020-01-17
```

i have done query with this dummy data

```
WITH raw AS(
SELECT 'x' AS item
      , '2018-01-12' AS start_date
      , 5800 AS val
      , 50 AS dep_rate
      , CURRENT_DATE() AS end_date

UNION ALL

SELECT 'y'
       , '2015-06-01'
       , 9200
       , 20
       , CURRENT_DATE()
)

-- SELECT *
--   FROM raw

, gen_year AS(
SELECT item
    , DATE_TRUNC(year, MONTH) AS year
FROM raw
, UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',start_date), CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) AS year
)

SELECT item
       , year
       , test
       , dep_rate
       , COALESCE(val, LAG(val) OVER(PARTITION BY item ORDER BY year) - LAG(dep_val) OVER(PARTITION BY item ORDER BY year)) AS val
       , COALESCE(dep_val, COALESCE(val, LAG(val) OVER(PARTITION BY item ORDER BY year) - LAG(dep_val) OVER(PARTITION BY item ORDER BY year)) *test/12*50/100) AS dep_val
  FROM (
        SELECT *
               , test/12 * dep_rate/100 * val AS dep_val
          FROM (
                SELECT g.item
                    , g.year
                    , 12 AS test
                    , r.val
                    , LAST_VALUE(r.dep_rate IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY g.item ORDER BY year ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS dep_rate
                FROM gen_year AS g
                    LEFT JOIN raw AS r ON r.item = g.item
                                    AND DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',r.start_date), MONTH) = year
                )
          )
```

the query above just fill null value on the 1 following row, not the rest of null value

```
item |  year     | test | dep_rate |val     |   dep_val 
 x   |2018-01-01 |   12 |    50    | 5800.0 |    2900.0
 x   |2019-01-01 |   12 |    50    | 2900.0 |    1450.0
 x   |2020-01-01 |   12 |    50    |  null  |    null
 y   |2015-06-01 |   12 |    20    | 9200.0 |   1840.0
 y   |2016-06-01 |   12 |    20    | 7360.0 |   3680.0
 y   |2017-06-01 |   12 |    20    |  null  |    null
 y   |2018-06-01 |   12 |    20    |  null  |    null
 y   |2019-06-01 |   12 |    20    |  null  |    null
```

dep_val calculation is

> val * dep_rate/100 * test/12

i want to fill the null value with this calculation..

> val on the previous row - dep_val on the previous row

the result i looking for is like this

```
item |  year     | test | dep_rate |val     |   dep_val 
 x   |2018-01-01 |   12 |    50    | 5800.0 |    2900.0
 x   |2019-01-01 |   12 |    50    | 2900.0 |    1450.0
 x   |2020-01-01 |   12 |    50    | 1450.0  |    725
 y   |2015-06-01 |   12 |    20    | 9200.0 |   1840.0
 y   |2016-06-01 |   12 |    20    | 7360.0 |   1472
 y   |2017-06-01 |   12 |    20    |  5888  |    1177
 y   |2018-06-01 |   12 |    20    |  4711  |    942.2
 y   |2019-06-01 |   12 |    20    |  3768  |    753.76
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and ends up being quite simple ...

```
#standardSQL
SELECT item,  
  DATE_TRUNC(DATE_ADD(bought_date, INTERVAL index YEAR), MONTH) year, 
  depreciation_rate,
  ROUND(price * POW((1 - depreciation_rate / 100), index), 2) AS val,
  ROUND(price * POW((1 - depreciation_rate / 100), index) * depreciation_rate / 100, 2) AS dep_val
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, DATE_DIFF(end_date, bought_date, YEAR))) AS index
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'x' item, DATE '2018-01-12' bought_date, 5800 price, 50 depreciation_rate, DATE '2020-01-17' end_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'y', '2015-06-01', 9200, 20, '2020-01-17' 
)
SELECT item,  
  DATE_TRUNC(DATE_ADD(bought_date, INTERVAL index YEAR), MONTH) year, 
  depreciation_rate,
  ROUND(price * POW((1 - depreciation_rate / 100), index), 2) AS val,
  ROUND(price * POW((1 - depreciation_rate / 100), index) * depreciation_rate / 100, 2) AS dep_val
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, DATE_DIFF(end_date, bought_date, YEAR))) AS index
-- ORDER BY item, year
```

with result

```
Row item    year            depreciation_rate   val         dep_val  
1   x       2018-01-01      50                  5800.0      2900.0   
2   x       2019-01-01      50                  2900.0      1450.0   
3   x       2020-01-01      50                  1450.0       725.0   
4   y       2015-06-01      20                  9200.0      1840.0   
5   y       2016-06-01      20                  7360.0      1472.0   
6   y       2017-06-01      20                  5888.0      1177.6   
7   y       2018-06-01      20                  4710.4       942.08  
8   y       2019-06-01      20                  3768.32      753.66  
9   y       2020-06-01      20                  3014.66      602.93
```

Answer (score 1):

See my query below for a bit of a round-a-bout solution.
The key item is the `sum(log(1-dep_rate/100)) over (partition by item order by year)`, which will generate a cumulative 'log factor', which you will then exponentiate and multiply by the original value to get the value for each year.

```
WITH raw AS(
  SELECT 'x' AS item, '2018-01-12' AS start_date, 5800 AS val, 50 AS dep_rate, CURRENT_DATE() AS end_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'y', '2015-06-01', 9200, 20, CURRENT_DATE()
),
gen_year AS(
  SELECT item, DATE_TRUNC(year, MONTH) AS year
  FROM raw, UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',start_date), CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) AS year
),
temp as (
  select item, year, dep_rate, val, sum(log(1-dep_rate/100)) over (partition by item order by year asc) as log_factor
  from gen_year
  left join raw using(item)
),
temp2 as (
  select *, val * exp(log_factor) as dep_val, row_number() over (partition by item order by year asc) as rn from temp
),
temp3 as (
  select *, lag(dep_val,1) over (partition by item order by year asc) as lagged_dep_val from temp2
),
temp4 as (
  select item,year,dep_rate, case when rn = 1 then val else lagged_dep_val end as val, dep_val from temp3
)
select item, year, dep_rate, round(val,2), round(val-dep_val,2) as dep_val from temp4
```